# Validating a login and creating sessions using PHP

Tags: php, session

Trying to validate a login in PHP but not quite getting the hang of it. The problem with this code is that even if the login is not valid and does not match the data in the database, it will still log them in. The redirect code at the bottom works fine. Any ideas?

**CODE:**

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM user WHERE username='" . $_POST["username"] . "' and password = '" . $_POST["password"] . "'");

$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
if (is_array($row)) {
    $_SESSION["user_id"] = $row[user_id];
    $_SESSION["user_name"] = $row[username];
} else {
    echo = "Invalid Username or Password!";
}

if ($_SESSION["user_name"] == 'ADMIN') {
    header("Location: admin.php");
} else {
    header("Location: useroptions.php");
}
```

Comment: `Obligatory PDO/SQL Injection blurb`

Comment: your last else will always run unless the user is admin. Perhaps you should add die to your 1st else

Comment: 1) What about using mysqli/pdo instead of mysql? 2) what about changing the (isarray) with mysql_num_rows?

Comment: What about password hashing ?

Comment: Please tell me this isn't actually your login script? And your not actually storing plain text passwords, and leaving input conditions un-sanitised...   Also your script will ALWAYS goto useroptions.php whether the login works or not..

Comment: http://thedailywtf.com/Articles/WellIntentioned-Destruction.aspx The location header may or not be respected, so relying on this sort of redirect is problematic. If respected,there is only one way through your application that leads to the admin.php - statement, obvioulsy: If $_SESSION["user_name"] was "ADMIN" before the execution of the database - query and no result is found.

Comment: @user2191572 - while I appreciate it's getting really tiresome making the same point about mysql_* deprecation and SQL injection vulnerabilities, I don't think your comment is actually going to achieve anything. The asker in all likelihood has no idea what you're talking about with that comment, so it really becomes just a cute in-joke to other people on the site. I think it's worth explaining these things properly so the asker learns their mistakes, rather than getting a cheap laugh, funny though your comment was :P

Comment: @Hecksa I am glad you were able to see the humor in it and yes I am 100% aware that it is somewhat of an inside joke but I actually provided an answer to this post and recommended PDO at the end =)

Comment: @user2191572 - Yep, I spotted the answer and +1'd it. I just think it's important to make sure we get important considerations like SQL injection / function deprecation across in a way that the asker, and also people visiting the question in the future, can learn from.

Comment: The edit to your answer was awesome too :D

Comment: @Hecksa Haha thanks! I'm glad you like it but it does make me wonder how on Earth is the `Obligatory blurb` supposed to help people if the BIG RED sign in the manual doesn't deter people. I think the entire page should be red and the user needs to sign in blood before they can view the content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM user WHERE username='" . $_POST["username"] . "' and password = '". $_POST["password"]."'");

$row  = mysql_fetch_array($result);

if(is_array($row)) 
{
    $_SESSION["user_id"]   = $row[user_id];
    $_SESSION["user_name"] = $row[username];

    if($_SESSION["user_name"] == 'ADMIN'){
        header("Location: admin.php");
    } else {
        header("Location: useroptions.php");
    }

} else {
    echo "Invalid Username or Password!";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you might have some logic issues, try this:

```
<?php
session_start();

$sql = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE username='" . $_POST["username"] . "' and password = '" . $_POST["password"] . "'";
$query = mysql_query($sql);
$count = mysql_num_rows($query);

if($count === 1)
{
    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
    $_SESSION["user_id"] = $row[user_id];
    $_SESSION["user_name"] = $row[username];

    if($_SESSION["user_name"] == 'ADMIN')
    {
        header("Location: admin.php");
    }
    else
    {
        header("Location: useroptions.php");
    }
}
else
{
    echo = "Invalid Username or Password!";
}
?>
```

I highly recommend looking into using a PDO connection because it will be much more portable and parameterized queries pretty much eliminate security issues if used properly.

All mysql_* functions are going to be deprecated as well so you should invest your time in learning the newest standards. A mechanic is not going to focus on learning carborated engines, they are going to focus on fuel-injection systems.

**The big red sign is a sign to stop using these functions:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM user WHERE username='" . $_POST["username"] . "' and password = '". $_POST["password"]."'");

$row  = mysql_fetch_array($result);
if(is_array($row)) {
$_SESSION["user_id"] = $row[user_id];
$_SESSION["user_name"] = $row[username];
} 

else {
echo "Invalid Username or Password!";
exit(); 
}

if($_SESSION["user_name"] == 'ADMIN'){
header("Location: admin.php");
exit(); 
}
else {
header("Location: useroptions.php");
exit();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Now your login will valid your data is not match with database because your have a little space   username='" . $_POST["username"]. "' and password = '".$_POST["password"]."'
Now try it........

```
  $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM user WHERE username='".$_POST["username"]."' and password = '".$_POST["password"]."'");

    $row  = mysql_fetch_array($result);
    if(is_array($row)) {
    $_SESSION["user_id"] = $row[user_id];
    $_SESSION["user_name"] = $row[username];
    } 

    else {
    $message = "Invalid Username or Password!";
    }

    if($_SESSION["user_name"] == 'ADMIN'){
    header("Location: admin.php");
    }
    else {
    header("Location: useroptions.php");
    }
```